# Automatically call parent method in its overriding implementations

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm using Python 3.10. I have a parent class that has access to some diagnostic object, e.g. a timer:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Parent(ABC):
    def __init__(self, timer):
        self.t = timer

    @abstractmethod
    def run():
        pass
```

I now have a bunch of child classes that implement `run()`:

```
class Child1(Parent):
    def run():
        print("Foo")

class Child2(Parent):
    def run():
        print("Bar")

...
```

I want the above inheritance to, implicitly, be equivalent to

```
class Child1(Parent):
    def run():
        self.t.start()
        print("Foo")
        self.t.stop()

class Child2(Parent):
    def run():
        self.t.start()
        print("Bar")
        self.t.stop()
...
```

without me adding the `start()` and `stop()` calls explicitly. The act of inheriting `run()` should be enough to surround all overriding implementations with suchlike calls -- a sort of "setup and teardown" that makes use of an object field. Is this possible?

---

Note that this isn't quite the same as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66581157/how-to-enforce-mandatory-parent-method-call-when-calling-child-method), where the solution is to raise an exception if the programmer doesn't manually add those calls into the implementation. That's almost the opposite of what I want: the calls should *not* be added.

Comment: I would suggest that a better pattern to look at would be a proxy which does the timing rather than having the super class hold the timer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python parent class 'wrapping' child-class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065112/python-parent-class-wrapping-child-class-methods) or [Python Wrap Class Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780907/python-wrap-class-method)

Comment: This is not how inheritance works. One way you *could* set this up is to simply have the `Parent` class define `run` to call *another* method which is the one that is overriden in the subclasses

Comment: Does the accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052736/python-proxy-class) help at all?